# Change headline text when clicking on multiple buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I have two or more buttons and whenever I click on a button, I want my text to change. Any ideas?

```js
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Change me!</h1>
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <button>Button 3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic react question. I advice you to read the [react documentation](https://react.dev/learn):

```js
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Change me!");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setText("button 1")}>Button 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setText("button 2")}>Button 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => setText("button 3")}>Button 3</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```